# Print 40 messages in one second. Prints have to be spread evenly across one second

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below prints "Hello" 40 times every second. I would like these 40 prints to be spread evenly across one second. As it stands at the moment the 40 prints happen in the first few milliseconds and the the program sleeps the rest of the time.

```
import time

start = time.time()
count =0

while True:
    print("Hello")
    end = time.time()
    count +=1
    if (end - start) <= 1 and count == 40:
        sleep_time = 1 - (end - start)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        count = 0
        end = 0
        start = time.time()
```

Comment: Update the `sleep_time` at the desired frequency ? Here `1/40` ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. This assumes that the print itself is instant which depending on the system, etc. might be far from the truth. So before you *space* the `prints` out in time, you have to subtract 40 times the duration of 1 such print and divide the result with 39.

Comment: "Evenly" is impossible in a high level language. You will always have nano to microseconds (even mili) of divergence in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement containing your `sleep` call won't run until `count` reaches 40, which is clearly not what you r want. Clearly, `sleep` should always be called. You can make a self-adjusting timer by making the sleep interval a function of the remaining prints and time:

```
duration = 1.0
target = 40

start = time.time()
while True:
    print("Hello")
    target -= 1
    if target:
        time.sleep((duration + start - time.time()) / target)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Anyone else missing a `sleep_until` to be able to take into account compute time?

Comment: @Adirio. That would require polling, which increases commutation time.

Comment: No, it just computes the time to sleep based on the target date. This means that if your task duration is variable you would still be doing periodic tasks. Lets say you want to run a task every second (T=1s) and that the task takes between 10 and 500 ms. With sleep, at t=0 you run your first task which takes t_1 (10-500ms), then you sleep for a second. So the second task starts at t=1+t_1 and takes t_2 (10-500ms), then you sleep for a second. Task 3 starts at t=2+t_1+t_2, task 4 at t=3+t_1+t_2+t_3, .... As you can see the error is getting higher.

Comment: `sleep_until` instead computes the starting time and adds the period T to compute the target time for the next task, executes this task, gets the new time and sleeps the remaining duration until the next task. This way they will always start at t=0, t=1s, t=2s, t=3s unless the task takes longer than T, but we already said that T=1s and the tasks take as much as 0.5s.

Comment: This is how periodic tasks are done in RT (real time) systems. RT oriented programming languages, which obviously Python is not one of, give you the `sleep_until` function already and you do not have to compute all those times, just add 1 period every task and sleep until that time. Thats is why I said I miss `sleep_until`.